# Embedding custom Google Map to website with markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to embed google map with custom markers to a website just by iframe? I have google map on my website with markers and everything is working with some functions in javascript. It's okay but now I want to enable some users to add same map with same markers to their website. I want to do it very easy and with less code possible. So I want to give code to users that they add to site and everything would work. Is it possible with just iframe tag? Or I must give users code in javascript too? Or is there another way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Mapsengine](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/) to create the map, they may easily be shared via iframe.  But there is no option to apply custom script-code.

Another approach: use a script-file that contains the code used with the map and that also creates the map. The users may embed this script instead of an iframe, the sharing would be as simple as when you would use an iframe.